# What is the word for an object of a disciplinarian?

Tags: word-choice

Stated another way, who does a disciplinarian discipline? Is there a word that is equivalent of lessor -> “lessee”?

"The headmaster was a disciplinarian. For the most minor of offences he would take the a student to his office and beat them. The result was not that the ______ reformed but that the _______ hated the headmaster."

Comment: "Disciplinarian" can refer to a wide variety of positions: teacher, parent, sports referee/umpire, judge, other public functionaries. And it's as descriptive of a person's attitude as their actions: you can be a disciplinarian even if you don't have anyone to discipline. Merriam-Webster has [discipliner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discipliner) for a person actually disciplining, which might be what you are asking about (maybe you can partner that with disciplinee). Think about the precise situation and provide an example situation.

Comment: Unless you're looking for *masochist* or *submissive*, which would also fit in some (sexual) contexts.

Comment: @StuartF, no, the context is more traditional. Like the example someone added of a schoolmaster.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, there is no specific term for the members of an organization upon which a disciplinarian exerts [his/her] [influence/rule] as regards discipline.

It is possible to characterize collectively the persons affected by the code a disciplinarian uses and/or instaures; there is for example the word "*brood*" (Usu. *derogatory*); it is a literary term.

> (SOED) **brood** **3** A race, a kind, a group of men, things, etc. having common qualities (Usu. *derogatory*)

Thus you may say something such as follows.

- A disciplinarian rules over his/her *brood* largely seconded by  the fear of punishment.
- A disciplinarian enforces discipline over his *brood* or defines the discipline that they should go by.

The word "*flock*" is also a possibility, there being no derogatory connotations to this one, but as the preceding it is not a technical term; it is purely literary.

> (SOED) **flock** **3b** A group of people, as children, pupils, etc. under the charge or guidance of one or more persons, as parents, teachers, etc.

- Disciplinarians instill the respect of discipline into their *flock*.

Comment: What about for a singular individual? Such as a ward to a guardian?

Comment: @nsayer You are talking about the condition of being subject to a guardian, and such a condition does involve submission to a certain discipline imposed by the guardian, but it seems to me that this is an accessory aspect of the condition, the main idea being that of protection; moreover this is a very particular case, whereas your question is much more encompassing, it being concerned with disciplinarians in general; for instance a religious disciplinarian is not concerned with protection on such a practical level.

Comment: No, I mentioned “guardian” only by comparison as it has the companion word “ward.” There are many other pairings of a similar sort - master/slave being another. I am searching for the similar word for disciplinarian.

Comment: @nsayer I told you, it seems there is no such corresponding word for "disciplinarian"; this is so possibly because there is not much interaction between the disciplinarian and the persons subjected to the dicipline; this fact becomes more evident when one considers that a disciplinarian, if not just an advocate of strict discipline, is a disciplinarian as part of another occupation, which constitutes his/her main task (for instance, army officers).